# Python error, something to do with mutable Series object not being hashed

Tags: python, pandas

The error messages are below. The first line is the piece of code that sparks the error.

```
x = some_data_frame.loc(~some_data_frame['some_column'].isin(some_list))
 line 112, in __call__: 
    axis = self.obj._get_axis_number(axis)
line 402, in _get_axis_number:
    axis = cls._AXIS_ALIASES.get(axis, axis)
line 1886, in __hash__:
    " hashed".format(self.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Why is this failing? Can you tell from the errors what is likely causing the error exactly? Why is it complaining about hashing? `some_data_frame` is a dataframe with a column `some_column`, it is not a series, nor is the column name wrong. I checked all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you should use `[]` instead of `()` for `some_data_frame.loc` in this case.

Try this:

```
x = some_data_frame.loc[~some_data_frame['some_column'].isin(some_list)]
```